# Topology. Understanding what a base is intuitively

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A collection $\{V_n\}$ is said to be base for $X$ if the following is true: For every $x$ that's an element of $X$ and every open set $G$ that is a subset of $X$ such that $x$ is an element of $G$, we have $x$ is an element of $V_n$. In other words, every open set in $X$ is a union of a subcollection of $\{V_n\}$.

I just don't have a real intuitive understanding of what this means. So proving that every separable space has a countable base is a little difficult for me. Is there any way someone can explain to me these concepts in a geometric sense or any really intuitive sense?

Comment: "So proving that every seperable space has a countable base" <- That's not true in general. It is for metric spaces, but non-metrisable separable spaces need not be second countable.

Comment: I know this is 5 years too late maybe, but shouldn't it be $V_n \subset G$? Because else $G$ would be a subset of the union instead of being the union of a subcollection of $V_n$.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a very simple motivating example.

Remember when you first learned about limits in your first calculus class? The definition wasn't phrased in terms of open sets: it was phrased in terms of open *intervals*. e.g. a function $X \to Y$ is continuous at $x \in X$ if and only if, for every open interval $V \subseteq Y$ such that $f(x) \in V$, there exists an open interval $U \subseteq X$ with $x \in X$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V$.

And indeed, the open intervals are a basis for the topology on the real line.

(actually, it was phrased specifically in terms of open balls centered on the stated points, rather than arbitrary open intervals)

For various reasons, it can be simpler to work with particular subcollections of open sets rather than all of them; the definition of a basis for a topology is precisely the condition you need to be able to recover the topology from the basis.